# Add allowed file extensions in Views Send file field

Tags: files, views

Using the [Views Send](https://drupal.org/project/views_send) module to send mass email.
On the email creation page I want to set my custom validation extensions for the file field provided by Views Send in combination with MimeMail (r# 267 in views_send.module).

For the file field I am trying to set the only allowed extension to be of type **.docx** by using the following function:

```
function my_module_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if($form_id == "views_form_views_send_page") {
    if ($form_state['step'] == 'views_send_config_form') {

      $form['mail']['views_send_attachments'] = array(
        '#type' => 'file',
        '#title' => t('Attachment'),
        '#upload_validators' => array(
          'file_validate_extensions' => array('docx'),
        ),
     );
  }
}
```

Unfortuanetely this is not working. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

Turns out the file behavior you're looking for is not defined for `file` elements, but for `managed_files`. It's as easy as:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function my_module_form_views_form_send_page_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  if ($form_state['step'] == 'views_send_config_form') {
    $form['mail']['views_send_attachments']['#type'] = 'managed_file';
    $form['mail']['views_send_attachments']['#upload_validators']['file_validate_extensions'][] = 'docx';
  }
}
```

But views_send will have to be patched to support managed_files. This still needs work in the [issue queue](https://drupal.org/node/2076659).

---

Yet, as I mention in the issue, you can hack it directly in the module. It's not recommended, but we don't have a hook here and the issue above might take a while to be solved. So just change the line

```
$file = file_save_upload('views_send_attachments', array(), $dir);
```

to

```
$file = file_save_upload('views_send_attachments', array('file_validate_extensions' => array('docx')), $dir);
```

Comment: When I make it a managed file Views Send is complaining: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in views_send_confirm_form() (regel 483 van /var/www/example.com/sites/all/modules/contrib/views_send/views_send.module)

Comment: To clarify better, I want to set my custom validation extensions for the file field provided by Views Send in combination with MimeMail (r# 267 in views_send.module)

Comment: Hm, I was just being naive. If you want to use `managed_file` then you'll have to patch views_send. It's an easy patch, though. I'll see you in the issue queue.

Comment: Thanks, I opened up an issue there as well https://drupal.org/node/2076659

Comment: Thanks, I tried that myself already but this is exactly what I am trying to avoid so I was hoping for another solution. I was thinking about creating a patch to add another textfield to the admin page where you can set your allowed extensions and then do a simple check with variable_get in file_save_upload